# How can I animate multiple objects across a web page in Javascript based on json data?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I have some json along the lines of

```
{
    "user1": [{"distance": 1, "pace": 100 }, {"distance": 4, "pace": 120}, {"distance": 9, "pace": 110}],
    "user2": [{"distance": 1, "pace": 110 }, {"distance": 7, "pace": 130}, {"distance": 14, "pace": 140}],
}
```

In total there are up to 30 users, with each user having up to 500 'frames'.

I want to animate an icon (svg or png or css) for each user simultaneously so that all 30 users can go across the screen.

How can I do this, ideally in a way that would play nicely with react.js as I will probably be using that to handle other things on the screen.

Alternatively, can I do it purely in react.js and with natively javascript?

Comment: Questions asking for "the best library to do this" are considered "off-topic" here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Well... If you are using react.js... then that rules out most of the animation libraries... So you will have to implement it by yourself...it can be as simple as adding a function call ( which will update user's positions) in your react render code. If you know react... then it should be a piece of cake. Just keep on forcing the re-render again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to store the progress (e.g. milliseconds since start) in state, and have each person component figure out its position based on the array and that number.  You can just do something like this:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  var start = Date.now();
  var tick = function(){
    this.setState({time: Date.now() - start});
  };
  setInterval(tick.bind(this), 16);
},
render: function(){
  var people = this.props.people;
  return <div>{
    Object.keys(people).map(function(key){
      return <Person data={people[key]} time={this.state.time} key={key} />
    }.bind(this));
  }</div>
}
```